# Check if any file is existing else do the command

Tags: python

I'm given a task to detect if there is a file inside a path, if there is no file then sleep and wait until there is a file existing else do the command.

**Here is my code**

```
import os,time

path = 'C:\\Users\\test'
for dir, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    while not files:
        print("no files at this level")
        time.sleep(1)
    if files:
        print("file detected")
```

Even I put the file inside the path, it keeps sleeping, it does not `print file detected`, What is wrong with this?

Comment: `files` won't change in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os,time

def file_exists(path):
    for dir, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        return files

path = r'C:\Users\test'
while True:
    if file_exists(path):
        print("file detected")
        break
    else:
        print("no files at this level")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

`files` won't change in the `while` loop. You'll have to `os.walk` again.

```
import os,time

def file_exists(path):
    for dir, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        return files

path = r'C:\Users\test'
while True:
    if file_exists(path):
        print("file detected")
        break
    else:
        print("no files at this level")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Here we have an infinite loop. If a file is found we call `break` and exit the loop.

My first answer used a nested combination of `while` and `for` and the `break` only exited the inner loop, so that wasn't going to work.

Comment: but the print("file detected") is not printed after i dragged my file inside the path

Comment: then I tried to put it before the break, but it loops infinitely, just new to python